# Caching best practice for AngularJS dynamic sites?

Tags: angularjs, caching

I'm working on an AngularJS project that will have considerable traffic.

While in development I'm stumbled upon the issue with partials cached and not updated on different actions. Sure, I can get rid of this using .run with $templateCache.removeAll(); for example, 
but want to make sure this is actually a good idea.

Some partials are updated dynamically (user input, or automatically in intervals), while some are static or updated very infrequently.

What would be the best approach to caching in this case?

With non-angular sites I prefer to keep responsibilities cleanly split, for ex.:
 1. Cache-headers are set on app level
 2. nginx - just to serve sites per se
 3. Varnish doing FPC + CDN for static assets or CDN doing full page caching (depending on a client/project, etc.) etc. etc. etc. 
 Key point: every part has its own distinct responsibility.

With this project I can use Varnish and CDN for static assets,
multi-server setup. Possibility to re-use Varnish for loadbalancing as well, i.e. I may have Varnish above several web-nodes. I have some flexibility in terms of infrastructure.

Please share your thoughts on the optimal setup?
In particular: is it still worth caching partials? 
If yes, what would be the best place to set CC headers?
What would be the best way to flush their cache then, esp. if I need to flush only some sub-selection?

Thank you!!
D.

Comment: I would concatenate all your html templates into a js file with something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache and then cache bust it with something like https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer myself, as cannot select **rob's** reply as an answer. My solution is based on his suggestion which helped me a lot to move forward:

During the production build:

1. I'm using "gulp-rev-easy" gulp module for revving the previously
   concatenated and uglified css & js files.
2. However, no existing revving modules could provide me with functionality I needed: replacing specific strings in an index.html template file with my own paths to CDN both for CSS and JS scripts. So I had to add my own function/override reveasy a little.
3. As per **rob's** I've started using templatecache and its works great in conjunction with revving.
4. Images are just going through a S3 -> CDN pair.

Some quick notes:

1. Using revving for "breaking" cache turned out to be the fastest and
   easiest way to deal with caching, as CloudFront is taking approx. 20
   minutes to invalidate a path, other CDNs - less, but you still have
   to issue the request etc.
2. For dynamically updated images having same names, like avatar images
   that a user can update via his profile areas, I suggest adding a
   timestamp or some random string to the file name. While adding a
   random URL path sounds easier, you won't be able to cache this.

Hope this helps,
Dennis